# If else within a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, rendering

Each of the user relations object looks like this:

```
"userRelations": [
    {
      "relatedUser": {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "lastName": "Miller"
      },
      "type": "FRIEND"
    },
    {
      "relatedUser": {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Rhena",
        "lastName": "Tahoma"
      },
      "type": "CONTACT"
    }
  ]
```

Currently, my code renders all relatedUsers. However, I only want to render those which have "type": "contact". Is it
  possible to check for this condition within the return

```
type RelatedUser = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    id: string,
    phoneNumber: string,
  };

  type RelationType = {
    type: string,
  };

export const ContactList: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({ data }) => {
  if (!data) return null;
  return (
    <View style={styles.users}>
    {data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(
      (item: { relatedUser: RelatedUser, type: RelationType}) => {
        const userName = item.relatedUser.firstName.concat(' ').concat(item.relatedUser.lastName);
        // if (item.type: "CONTACT"){
        return (
          <View style={styles.item} key={item.relatedUser.id}>
            <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      },
    )}
  </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You might want to `.filter()` your array just before `.map()`: `.filter(({ type }) => type === 'CONTACT')`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing that inside map's return I would suggest to chain `.filter()` with `map()`:

```js
userRelations.filter(({ type }) => type === 'CONTACT').map(/* your code*/)
```

Comment: ```{data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.filter(({ type }) => type === 'CONTACT').map(``` gives me ```Binding element 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)```error. and if I add : RelationType infront of type, I get ```'RelationType' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Binding element 'RelationType' implicitly has an 'any' type.```

Comment: looks like a clean solution tho

Comment: Yes, but adding ```type: string```gives the same error

Comment: @Jnl you were specifying the array element type on as a type annotation on the `map` callback parameter (`(item: { relatedUser: RelatedUser, type: RelationType})`). When you do that, you actually silences type checking errors. Use type inference as suggested in this answer.

Comment: Solution: declare `data.users.nodes[0].userRelations: { relatedUser: RelatedUser, type: RelationType}[]`

Comment: Didn't I already do what the answer suggested? I am not sure if I understand you correctly @AluanHaddad

Comment: @Jnl I don't know because you didn't include the definition of the `UserProps` types in your question. If you tried to, there may be a typo. Anyway, type annotations on callback parameters hide these kinds of errors.

Comment: User props ``` data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult;```but I don't think that has anything to do w the problem here. @AluanHaddad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215583/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-jnl).

Comment: @user0101 do you get why that error might be? any solution?